# What could be the meaning of variable in all capital letters?

Tags: c#, coding-style, naming-conventions

As question states, I am doing homework which have 2 variables BOOK, and MAGAZINE in all capital letters, and I can not figure out what could be the purpose of it.

Anyone have a clue?

The icon in Visio Class Diagram looks like rectangle with equal sign on it and a lock declaring it private.

[This is a picture of class diagram.](http://kool-invention.mine.nu/classdiagram.png)

Regards.

Comment: More detail, please. Are you referring to test on a class diagram? Post it. In all likelihood, though, the capitalization means nothing at all.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: Let me upload it somewhere. One minute.

Comment: I do not use ALLCAPS in C# except for DEFINES. However, in a number of languages, ALLCAPS are used for "constants". YMMV: it's all conventions.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: I can't uploat a picture atm. I only have 1 reputation.

Comment: I have added a link to PNG file.

Comment: Looks like an enumeration to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are private constants.  You can tell by the icon next to their name.  Take a look at the constant TEST in this example...

[image: Screen shot of private const in C# with intelisense]

EDIT:
The all caps is merely by convention, but is usually used to represent constants.

Comment: Ok, that is great to know. But, the problem is that I have done whole program with out using it and I have no idea how to implement them. You have any idea?

Comment: Could you post the full problem?  I assume you are trying to write a program that matches that class diagram, but we have no idea what that program might be.

Comment: Ok, I will add class diagram now. Ask me if you want to see the code I have.

Comment: I saw the class diagram, what I mean is what is the homework problem you are trying to complete?

Comment: Well, make the class diagram work with all components posted in it. This was only 1 class of 6 total. Basically I have a form in which I can add Book or Magazine in it by using object Book or Magazine and then show all entries in DisplayEntry forms textbox.

Answer (score 4):

Variables in all capital letters in any language generally refer to constants, meaning the value should never change.

In this case, they could refer to an enumerated type, which is a special sort of constant basically is just a symbol for itself.

Answer (score 1):

They're probably constants, defining maybe a key or index. Without a more specific question I can't give you anything but a vague answer, sorry.